# Add Html code with get post meta

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am confused with a simple issue, Actually, I am using Wordpress Custom fields using post meta

```
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );
```

Above meta code generate a value entered in a custom field.

But, I want to add html code around it.

If i add paragraph to it like this `<p> <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ); ?> </p>` then it is fine! but when field is empty then it shows a empty `<p></p>`

That's why i am looking to add a html in meta code so that if field is empty then no html code will be included in DOM.

And if field have text then it shows text with a html markup.

i am not sure how to do this!

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `wpautop()` function to automatically add paragraphs instead.

Example:

```
echo wpautop( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true ) );
```

You should probably be assigning this meta field to a variable first and checking the value is set before you attempt to output.

E.g.

```
$text_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_text_field', true );

if ( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
    echo wpautop( $text_field );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. paragraph is just a example of what i am trying to do. I want to add table code into it so that when new field populated then it come up within a table so that i can style it.